# Select onChange Calculator not working - How to solve?

Tags: select, calculator

So the context is to make a simple calculator, using only two operators: "Sum and subtract".
The calculator is using two number inputs, and one select that selects the operator.
The thing is:
1° - My const variable num1 and num2 are getting the type "null", and I honestly dont know why
2° - How do I put the result of the operation in the span of id "result".

The code i wrote was:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Type your first number" id="num1">
<select onchange="onChange(this.value)">
  <option value="+"> Sum </option>
  <option value="-"> Subtract </option>
</select>
<input type="number" placeholder="Type your second number" id="num2">
<h4> The result of the operation is: <span id="result"></span>
```

**JS:**

```
function onChange(value) {
 
  const num1 = document.getElementById("#num1".value);
  const num2 = document.getElementById("#num2".value);
  const result = document.getElementById("#result");
  function sum() {
    return num1 + num2
  }
  function sub() {
    return num1 - num2
  }
  if (value === "+") {
    console.log(`The operation to be performed is ${num1} + ${num2}. The result is: ${soma()}.`)
  } else {
    console.log(`The operation to be performed is ${num1} - ${num2}. The result is: ${sub()}.`)
  }
}
```

I tried changing the variables num1 and num2, writing:
`const num1 = document.getElementById("#num1").value;`

But it didn't work also.